# How to get the style content from html file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, rhino

I have 1 html file with internal styles defined within head.
I am using Rhino and reading this file using readFile(welcome.html)

I want to get all the contents between  ...  tags and have to write in another file or store in any string variable.

NOTE: I have to do this without using jQuery. because whenever i am using jQuery it showing me error as below

```
js: uncaught JavaScript runtime exception: ReferenceError: "$" is not defined.
```

so, Is it possible using only javascript/DOM...or if i use jQuery. how should i import it for javascript file using rhino....?

Comment: _"NOTE: I have to do this without using jQuery. because whenever i am using jQuery it showing me error as below"_ That's because your page doesn't actually include jQuery. Fix that, and you _can_ use jQuery.

Comment: I didn't test this but in JavaScript should be something like: `var style = document.getElementsByTagName("style").innerHTML;`

Comment: yes,true..@Matt Ball  now i am trying rhino load method to load jquery..let me see if it works!